# FFMPEG Windows Batch - Recursive Convert based and settings based on Frame Height

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

So I'm trying to make a batch file to use FFMPEG to convert around ~1000 MP4 video files.

I want to recursively go through these folders, possibly use ffprobe to discover the frame height, and then based on the frame height options (360, 480, 720, or 1080 frame height) give them individually different ffmpeg commands.

I've been reading up on various approaches to this just as far as batch processing goes.

So far I'm at this stage:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do C:\ffinstall\local64\bin-video\ffmpeg -i "%%a"  -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryslow -tune film -refs 8 -bf 6 -aq-mode 2 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=30:main_h-overlay_h-30,subtitles='D:\add.ass'" -c:a copy "encoded\%%~na.mp4"
```

pause

Code to discover the frame height:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 inputfile.mp4
```

Trying to figure out conditionals and how their syntax is.  Also I'm getting a  Unable to parse option value "add.ass" as image size error. Which I believe is due to not being to see the subtitle file.

Any suggestions on where I can start? Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's the difference in commands due to input height?

Comment: You've posted code which is irrelevant to your question because you've already told us that you will possibly have to use ffprobe. So find out how to use ffprobe, create your relevant code, test it and post back by editing your original question accordingly.

Comment: Mulvya- Different sized watermark and different overlay position for the watermark. For the really small files, a lower CRF number.